# Encoding in the mail message sending via php sockets

Tags: php, sockets, email, encoding

I'm trying to send message which content contains a cyrillic. I' write the follwoing code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("smtp.mdom.net", 25);
fputs($fp, "EHLO S\r\n");
fputs($fp, "auth login\r\n");
fputs($fp, "base64_login\r\n");
fputs($fp, "base64_pass\r\n");
fputs($fp, "mail from: mymail@mdom.net\r\n");
fputs($fp, "rcpt to: mymail@mdom.net\r\n");
fputs($fp, "data\r\n");
fputs($fp, "<html><body>SOME CYRILLIC TEXT</body></html>\r\n");
fputs($fp, ".\r\n");
```

But when I'm trying to recieve this message it doesn't have a valid encoding. E.g. `АБВГД` из displaying as `п░п▒п▓п⌠п■`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails, or even try to implement your own SMTP library. Just use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both of which handle all of those details for you.

Comment: @MarcB Can you answer my question?

Comment: That is the answer. Don't write code like this. You haven't done ANY of the steps necessary to get non-ascii text sent through SMTP. So don't even try. Use one of the libraries I mentioned and let it handle all the details.

Comment: @MarcB I want to know what headers I must to add to my message for the correctly displaying cyricllic.

Comment: Then go read up about MIME.

Comment: @MarcB Can you get a reference to an actuall RFC for mail headers?